# Avoid early exit from command in gitlab CI script pipeline while still capturing exit status

Tags: python, bash, gitlab-ci, pylint

I am trying to generate a badge from PyLint output in a Gitlab CI script. Eventually, the job should fail if PyLint has a non-zero exit code. But before it does so, I want the badge to be created. So I have tried the following:

```
before_script:
    - [...]
    - mkdir -p public
script:
    - pylint lib --disable R,missing-docstring,wrong-import-order --reports=y | tee public/pylint-report.txt
    - export SUCCESS=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
    - SCORE=$(tail -n 2 public/pylint-report.txt | grep -o -P "\d\d?\.\d+\/\d*" | head -1)
    - echo "PyLint score ${SCORE}"
    - python3.6 -m pybadges --left-text=PyLint --right-text=${SCORE} > public/pylint.svg
    - exit ${SUCCESS}
artifacts:
    when: always
    [...]
```

This works fine if the PyLint exit code is 0:

```
$ mkdir -p public
$ pylint lib --disable R,missing-docstring,wrong-import-order --reports=y | tee public/pylint-report.txt; export SUCCESS=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
[Pylint report output]
$ SCORE=$(tail -n 2 public/pylint-report.txt | grep -o -P "\d\d?\.\d+\/\d*" | head -1)
$ echo "PyLint score ${SCORE}"
PyLint score 10.00/10
$ python3.6 -m pybadges --left-text=PyLint --right-text=${SCORE} > public/pylint.svg
$ exit ${SUCCESS}
Uploading artifacts...
public/pylint-report.txt: found 1 matching files   
public/pylint.svg: found 1 matching files          
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=XXX responseStatus=201 Created token=XXX
Job succeeded
```

However, when PyLint exits with non-zero, the script is aborted after the first line:

```
$ mkdir -p public
$ pylint lib --disable R,missing-docstring,wrong-import-order --reports=y | tee public/pylint-report.txt
[Pylint report output]
Uploading artifacts...
public/pylint-report.txt: found 1 matching files   
WARNING: public/pylint.svg: no matching files      
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=XXX responseStatus=201 Created token=XXX
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

To clarify: I want the job to fail, but I want to make sure the script always runs all the lines. Only the `exit` command in the last line should determine the job status.

This runs in a container that uses the Bash.

I expected the `tee` command to always exit with 0 so that the first script line should never fail. But that does not seem to be the case.

I have tried appending a `|| true` call to the first line, but then the following line, `SUCCESS=${PIPESTATUS[0]}`, is always 0; perhaps this refers to the root cause.

Also, I have tried to append the `export` call (now second line) to the first line, separated by a semicolon. Again, no difference even though I also expected the `export` call always to exit with 0.

My question is hence: why can the first line of the script exit with a non-zero code? How do I prevent this?

Or maybe: is there an easier way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: *grumbles about a "script" being specified as a list rather than a multi-line string* -- the multi-line-string approach makes it much clearer that your code is passed to the shell exactly as-given, without things being done behind your back; whereas if they're assembling the list into a script themselves, what's to say they aren't adding logging or other instrumentation that impacts `$?`/`PIPESTATUS`/etc. behind your back too?

Comment: BTW, why use `export` at all, vs setting a regular shell variable stored in heap memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gitlab sets a bunch of "helpful" shell options you don't actually want. Among these is `errexit`, aka `set -e`, and `pipefail` (which is generally a good idea, but in conjunction with `set -e` means your script exits if any component of a pipeline fails).

To work around this one:

```
{ SUCCESS=0; pylint lib ...args... || SUCCESS=$?; } > >(tee public/pylint-report.txt)
```

We're sitting `SUCCESS` directly here (no need for `export`), so you don't need to refer to `PIPESTATUS` later. Branching on the return value of a command marks that command as "checked", so it isn't treated as a failure for purposes of `errexit`.

---

BTW, for background on `set -e` and why it's something you *really* don't want, see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises).

As another aside, all-caps variable names are used for variables meaningful to the shell or POSIX-specified tools, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to collide. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable will overwrite any preexisting like-named environment variable.

Comment: Not sure what the `> >` are supposed to do, but they result in a Yaml parsing error. Apart from that, this seems a good solution.

Comment: `>` alone is a redirection. `>(...)` is a process substitution; the shell replaces it with a name of a fifo which, when written to, redirects its output to a process running `...`. Combine the two, and you're redirecting your stdout to a FIFO that writes to a copy of `tee`, *without* using a pipeline. If it were a shell error I'd tell you to force bash to be used instead of sh, but for a yaml error I just suggest getting Python or something else that knows how to generate valid YAML to tell you how to quote it.

Comment: The whole string just needs to be double-quoted. Otherwise, works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Gitlab you are using, you might have more luck with an `after_script` section as an alternate way to run arbitrary code whether or not a process fails.

"`after_script` is used to define the command that will be run after all jobs, including failed ones. This has to be an array or a multi-line string."

[Link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script-and-after_script)

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure why it was downvoted either. Feel free to upvote it. I agree it's not a complete answer, but thought it might be worth mentioning. Let us know if you're able to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this after i found workaround and was very very mad what caused my scripts don't work ...

### Added into `before_script` into `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```bash
    - |
      # Gitlab trying to be smarter then you ... they just single-handedly defeated whole purpose of Docker container 
      # this is revert of their "awesome" idea
      # this setting should be used ONLY per script bases
      # behavior is unexpected and inconsistent when particular script has not been written with this in mind
      # Scripts are written by amateurs, ops, by somebody who has been developer, not operations, so:
      # - if i had build everything with this setting, it would be "safer" - sometimes ...
      # - but ... not really, @read: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#So-called_strict_mode
      # - but!: only per script bases rule applies never the less!
      # - NO runtime should ever change Docker environment like this
      # - there is NO documentation FOR IT IN GITLAB DOCS!
      # - seriously Gitlab!?
      # - @see https://elder.dev/posts/safer-bash/ -- for writing scripts like that,
      #   and Gitlab REQUIRES YOU TO WITHOUT DISCLOSING IT!
      #   - example of errexit: https://www.newline.co/courses/newline-guide-to-bash-scripting/errexit
      # - @see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html - for all env setting
      # - @see frutrated developers who faced this: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27668, https://www.adoclib.com/blog/gitlab-ci-exit-1-even-if-it-is-successful.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56079993/avoid-early-exit-from-command-in-gitlab-ci-script-pipeline-while-still-capturing, ...
      set +o errexit
      set +o pipefail
```

You can find this "helpful" (as [@charlesdufy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) put it) thing and my reaction to it [here - gitlab code comment & rant](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/commit/68a8a0e7fe4f022c6d3d72696c1f273195a69f5a#note_1016246702) - you can upvote or comment on it, to get it removed. I didn't see anything so insane as this in any big app like this.